# How to transfer table from one database to another in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, psql, pg-dump, copy

```
pg_dump -h host_ip -U postgres -d source_db -t aa_nqrgs.act_26022017  | 
    psql -h destination_host_ip -U postgres -d destination_db
```

I have tried this command to transfer a table from one server to another, but it shows an error like 'invalid command \N'. How can I resolve this?

Comment: you can use dblink to copy a table from one host to another.

Comment: "*invalid command \N*" is typically not the original error, but a result of a previous error in the script and the `copy` command can't continue properly. So you need to find out what went wrong. If you pass `-a` option to `psql` it will output all steps, thus giving you a hint on where the processing of the script failed.

Comment: As an alternative, you can also try to use a *Foreign Data Wrapper*, and [CREATE a foreign TABLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-createforeigntable.html)

Comment: `pg_dump` is much faster than insertion into FDW, in my experience.